# Tools for resolving catastrophic backtracking

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I'm asking in the general for a tool or method to find the "hot spot" in a regex which causes uncontrolled backtracking.  I have a fairly good grasp of possessive matching, negative lookahead assertions, atomic groups etc but I'm facing a situation where it's not clear where exactly my regex is wrong.

The problematic regex is a PCRE regex; but I'll be happy for any pointers for any language.

Ideally, I'd like to see a tool which would highlight the "hot spots" in a regex.  I have in the past tried to create a wrapper for `perl -Mre=debug` but couldn't really figure out how I should usefully process its output.  Vaguely, the idea would be to run one or more input strings against a regex, and collect the offset in the regex (as well as perhaps the offsets in the string) which the matcher keeps on coming back to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Damian Conway's brand new [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp::Debugger) module for Perl lets you watch an animation of your regex being matched against a string.  It should make it fairly easy to spot excessive backtracking.  Just install it and use the included `rxrx` script that lets you enter a regex and a string to match it against.

Answer (score 3):

I realize I'm late to the game, but check out this [regex tester](http://regex101.com) which features a regex debugger. Take a look at this example: http://regex101.com/r/pF9pC2/#debugger